# How to write regexp for this situation?

Tags: python-2.7

I have this pattern

```
PlayerName<UID><STEAM_ID><TEAM>

^(.+?)<(.+?)><(.+?)><(.+?)>$
```

And this looks like very easy to parse (i need to have saparately PlayerName, UID, STEAM_ID and TEAM). But playerName may have "<" and ">" into it. for example

```
SkOrPiOn <38> rus<1020><STEAM_0:0:985442350><Unassigned>
```

we get this

```
[('SkOrPiOn ', '38> rus<1020', 'STEAM_0:0:985442350', 'Unassigned')]
```

as you can see, result is wrong.

All what i can to do, this is the reverse string and regexp patter, to get this

```
[('dengissanU', '053244589:0:0_MAETS', '0201', 'sur >83< nOiPrOkS')]
```

Now i can reverse back this variables. But is there more right way to get what i need?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the first `?`. It's a modifier which means "match as few characters as possible". You want the default behavior which is to match as much as possible.

```
^(.+)<(.+?)><(.+?)><(.+?)>$
```